# Sequence of instruction execution in an assembly language program

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I got a question in my assembly language course exam yesterday in which we had to write the sequence in which the code will execute
The code is:

```
jmp start
tickcount: dw 0
kbisr:
in al, 0x60
cmp al, 0x2a
jne end
mov bl, 0x2a
end:
mov al, 0x20
out 0x20, al
iret
timerISR:
;---assume that keyboard was pressed by user at this point
push ax
inc word [cs:tickcount]; increment tick count
mov al, 0x20
out 0x20, al ; end of interrupt pop ax
iret
start:
xor ax, ax
mov es, ax
cli
mov word [es:9*4], kbisr
mov [es:9*4+2], cs
mov word [es:8*4], timerISR
mov [es:8*4+2], cs
;-------------------int 8h occurred here
sti
mov ax, 20
mov bx,15
add ax, bx
mov ax, 0x4C00
int 0x21
```

I believe that the code will start from "start" label and end at int 0x21 without entering into any hooked interrupt because the interrupt occurs when it is already disabled using cli.

Am I right?

Comment: Is the interrupt discarded or will it be called after sti?

Comment: that's the main confusion

Comment: IIRC, legacy interrupts are normally level-triggered; the pin stays asserted until the CPU handles it (and tells the interrupt controller to de-assert it?  I'm unclear on all the details).  So a pending interrupt is normally taken as soon as you `sti`.

Comment: 1. `kbisr` modifies `ax` and `bx`. 2. `timerISR` modifies `ax`. 3. `timerISR` leaves the stack unbalanced so this will crash. 4. You do not restore the interrupt handlers before terminating the program. This means the original handlers are never called again, your register modifying handlers are called, and the memory block holding your handlers is freed by the DOS. This will also possibly lead to crashes, and you cannot enter input anymore. 5. Your interrupt 8 handler doesn't increment the timer tick at 40h:6Ch.